# How do you find a company that will sponsor a visa?

Tags: job-search, relocation, visa

Lets say you don't have an EU passport, nor a US one (or working visas).

How can a fairly recent grad (in software, but let's assume any high tech job), who is a talented and passionate person, start the process of relocating?

- What are the most useful sites/other ways of finding overseas job offerings that will sponsor a visa? (looking at non relocation job offers overseas will likely fail due to the overhead needed in making the accommodations for the visa).
- How should one focus their career, so that in a few years they will be a prime candidate for relocation opportunities?

Comment: No personal experience however getting experience and developing your skills for the professional environment will help you relocate. You need to be able to prove you are better than every other candidate who applies locally and you have a higher chance of getting offers.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you also needing to find a job that will sponsor a visa for you? Relocation alone (the cost to move to a different city) is worthless if the company won't sponsor a visa.

Comment: @DavidK yes I meant that the main hurdle would be the visa bureaucracy. Regarding relocation costs, that's actually not an issue

Comment: Stack Overflow's [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?v=true&t=true) site has filters for listings offering visa sponsorship and/or paid relocation (they're under Perks).

Comment: There are a lot of risks when hiring foreigners you should probably get some professional experience in your country before you consider relocating it's always seniors who get relocated

Answer (score 4):

If I were you, I'd focus on your second point. Companies aren't going to look far afield or offer relocation support if there are acceptable local candidates. Other than exploitative H-1B temp factories, entry-level relocation opportunities are generally limited to niche fields like petrochemical engineering where there's not a large talent pool overall.

You need to build experience and your network first. Standard "how do I advance my career" advice applies here. If there's just not much of a job market around you, you might look for remote working opportunities, though those are likely to offer low pay and you should consider whether a given position will actually help you build your skill set.

Comment: To start point two you can also look for an international company in your region, so you can go for a relocation within the same company.

Answer (score 1):

Companies don't offer relocation jobs !

They have open positions and seek suitable candidates.

Those that don't accept non local applicants will usually include it in the posting.

If you apply to offers in other countries be certain to be qualified enough to justify the additional effort and potential costs.

Keep in mind, not everybody will cover relocation costs and / or travel and accomodation, those are part of the contract negotiation.

Also, before you apply, make sure you qualify for a visa in that country to avoid wasting time and money.

Visa costs are also part of the negotiation and not automatically reimbursed.

I wager, unless there is a shortage of workers in your field in that country / city, you, as a junior will have difficulty getting hired unless you foot most, if not all of the additional costs you might bring.

A companys' involvement into the visa process is usually as little as providing you with a letter stating their intention to hire you and the visa and travel formalities are taken care of by yourself.

It can however be the case that the company (if it's a really large one or one very versed in hiring foreign workers) makes all the necessary arrangements and you just have to show up for your flight.

Granted, that case is most likely if they are eager to hire you because you're that good or they need urgent help.

Answer (score 0):

> what hardships did it bring?

You leave behind your social support structure and sometimes language, it's an unknown how you will fare. Most people cannot handle it especially younger men. Females in my experience seem to do a bit better. More mature people of either sex tend to be more self-reliant. But one mistake/enemy when you are new can mar your whole experience.

A great deal depends on where you move to and where you move from and how long you intend to be their. First World to third World is a heartbreaker for almost everyone even short term, especially for couples. The other way around usually goes much better.

A big difference is how much of your emotional and mental baggage you take with you, my advice is to leave it behind as well.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically "relocation jobs" are rare finds and are mostly related to very niche roles of which software development is unlikely to be one of them. As a recent grad, unless you have already published a lot to github, applications in appstore....basically, unless you have a sturdy portfolio, or are a known and well regarded hacker is unlikely to be offered...

Again, unless the candidate pool is VERY small, then the relocation costs are not worth the effort for any hiring company.

You do have some examples of exceptions to this, but I would caution you to this. I believe I have seen recently some adverts for IT roles in the NHS (in the UK) where relocation grants are included, the only reason for this is that they simply can't find enough candidates in the area they are needing this extra boost of staff. The problem with it is that if you research enough you find that there is a current project that is running, so it is possible you would be hired and them dismissed when this is over.

Looking for overseas relocation gets even tougher, you will have, again, some niche areas where this happens, like at the moment the Treasury in New Zealand is hiring Business Analysts and they will cover relocation costs + visa application costs.

It is a lot easier for you to make the move yourself, applying for a visa if you need one and looking into moving into the country by your own means, this may mean you need to stay where you are for a while to have enough savings to make the move.

What is it like to relocate?

In all fairness, it is tough. If you do it on your own, you will lose all of your network support, as a young man this doesn't matter much at first, but then reality settles in. As life moves on and you eventually marry and have children you notice how there are many things that are way more challenging for you than they are for the "locals". You can't just call your mom to take care of the kids so you can go out with your wife for dinner.

In a more immediate way, you can't call your mom/dad for help with something that happened in your house. It is likely that you will have to pay full price for everything you need, which you might have gotten away with paying a lower cost in your country of origin due to your "safety" network.

It is also great for you, it puts you out of your comfort zone and forces you to strive to be better, if you don't put enough effort, you may end up facing so many challenges you may want to give up.

You face the possibility of just burning out and packing up and going back. This is not a decision to take lightly.

Currently I am in the process of working on relocation to the USA, I am working on several projects that improve business efficiency in the Europe area and Asian region, I have already discussed with my superiors that I want the USA office to make me an offer to move there as if they do they will pay relocation costs, if I continue to make such improvements in this area it is a natural progression for me to end up going there. So as others mentioned, it is a viable option to find a multinational company and work there and have the goal to relocate through them.